# Disk Backup with both Linux and Windows Partitions

Tags: backup, system

If I make a backup of my entire disk, which has both Ubuntu and Windows partitions (i.e. dual boot) using the Gnome Disk Utility (or eventually other utility), will I be able to restore both OSes? Are there any particular caveats I should be aware of? Otherwise, should I just backup the Linux partitions (I am more concerned with these than the Windows one)?

Comment: If UEFI yes, as long as you also backup the ESP.

Comment: Be more concerned with backing up just your user data. That will be much faster, so you will do it more frequently. An OS can be reinstalled. Your personal data, once lost, are lost forever.

Comment: Thank you @ChanganAuto If I create an .img file with the Gnome Disk Utility, can I copy it to an external hard drive formatted in NTFS, or should it be a Linux type partition?

Comment: Thank you @vanadium I already have a backup of all my files, but my Linux system has a huge number of development tools, and wish to avoid having to re-install all of these.